# Using Rx to synchronize two streams

Tags: .net, windows, system.reactive

I have a stream of data from the master source, and second stream with enrichment data from a different source.  Unfortunately, the enrichment messages often arrive before the original piece of data.  I'd like to ensure that the enrichment message is buffered until the original message is first published.  Can I achieve this with Rx?

Comment: Take a look on 101 Rx Samples http://rxwiki.wikidot.com/101samples

Comment: Is there always an associated enrichment value for every master value? Is it one-to-one? Otherwise you need to provide some code to be able to base an answer upon.

Comment: There may not be an enrichment value. I don't see how it makes a difference, the master message cannot be delayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, probably. As @Enigmativity eluded too, this stands as a somewhat open ended question.

1. Are there 1-to-1 messages (apparently not - 'There may not be an enrichment value')
2. Will the enrichment messages and master messages arrive in the same order. If not then I assume there is an Id of some sort to match an enrichment to a master message
3. It seems that the master message may not be delayed and must be pushed through as it arrives. How then are enrichment messages applied to the master message? Do we push a new message which is the Master+Enrichment? I assume you don't want to mutate state i.e. modify the Master message after it has been forward on.

Comment: Hi there.  Thanks for the reply.  In answer to your questions, 1 - no, unfortunately.  The enrichment comes from another service which may not be available.  2 - yes there's a correlation ID, 3 - something is listening to the enrichment messages and then mutates its own representation of the first message.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `ReplaySubject` in this situation. You can find working sample here: [How to subscribe to, but buffer data from, an IObservable until another IObservable has published?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7480644/how-to-subscribe-to-but-buffer-data-from-an-iobservable-until-another-iobserva). That code works great for me.

Comment: THanks but that's not quite what I'm trying to do